# same function return multiple values in terms of objects, array or function in javascript via design pattern?

Tags: javascript, angular, design-patterns

How can i return multiple values from the function in javascript. And how to use that.??

Comment: Return an Object, instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that.

But, you can return an `array` or an **object** which contains your values.

```js
function doSomething(a,b){
    return [a,b];
  //return {a,b};
}
console.log(doSomething(1,2));
```

If you want to return many values you can use `destructing` **operator** in order to find out all the values.

```js
function doSomething(a,b,c,d,e,f){
      return {a,b,c,d,e,f};
}
let {a,b,c,d,e,f}=doSomething(1,2,3,4,5,6);
console.log(a,b,c,d,e,f);
```

Comment: What the method return type would be if we wanted to see it in the signature ?

Answer (score 6):

Functions by definition can only return one value. However, you can pack your values in an array or an object:

```
function greeting(){
    return {
        name: "Andy",
        message: "Hello world"
    };
}
```